# Highlight the chart with different color when click on mschart

Tags: mschart

I build the chart by using of mschart.
   when the user click particular column in column chart ,  i want to highlight the that column with some other color till the user the click the other column

Is it possible in mschart?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You should change the background color of the datagridview that you are using.

```
dgv.Columns[colNr].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green
```